# Quarkus Http Cors accept JSON

Tags: cors, quarkus

How should I configure the cors policy so it accepts json?

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/todo/savePerson' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:

> Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

**application.properties:**

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:4200
quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept, origin, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,POST,OPTIONS
```

Comment: That url could be opened via browser?

Answer (score 3):

Yea, I tested it with Postman/Browser. I just deleted the rest and now it works for me.

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
```

Comment: While I upvoted the answer, one thing I ran into was, if you just use the above configuration, not all the response headers are passed back to the requestor and you would have to explicitly provide quarkus.http.cors.exposed-headers. Just in case if anyone runs into a similar issue. When I add any other headers, I ran into the exact issue as epox, and I overcome that by quarkus.http.cors.headers=content-type. You may need to add additional header types to allow based on your need